# Recursive function that gets rid of vowels

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive function that gets rid of all the vowels in a list.
For some reason my solution just returns an empty list and I don't understand how to fix it.
Here is my code:

```
def remove(seq):
    if not seq:
        return []
    elif isinstance(seq[0], list):
        return remove(seq[0]) + remove(seq[1:])
    elif seq[0] == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
        return remove(seq[1:])
    else:
        return seq[0] + remove(seq[1:])

    print(remove(["a", "b", "c", ["d", "e"], "f"])) just returns []
```

Comment: Because your base case is to return an empty list. Also, `seq[0] == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u"` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Please produce a [Minimal, Compact, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In this context, that means: how do you run this code?  What doesn't work, exactly?

Comment: You also need to return an empty string in first `if` condition.

Comment: @Galax Here is not incorrect. Because OP is concatenating string characters.

Comment: @Galax Sure, but I was just explaining to OP why it was returning an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fixed version:

```
def remove(seq):
    if not seq:
        return []
    elif isinstance(seq[0], list):
        return [remove(seq[0])] + remove(seq[1:])
    elif seq[0] in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
        return remove(seq[1:])
    else:
        return [seq[0]] + remove(seq[1:])

print(remove(["a", "b", "c", ["d", "e"], "f", "g", "h", "i"]))
```

Output:

```
['b', 'c', ['d'], 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

The first error was the way that you used the 'or' to compare with multiple values. You could write `seq[0] == "a" or seq[0] == "b" or ...`, or use an `in` and a sequence as I did. For better performance the vowels could be put into a set, like this:

```
vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}

def remove(seq):
    if not seq:
        return []
    elif isinstance(seq[0], list):
        return [remove(seq[0])] + remove(seq[1:])
    elif seq[0] in vowels:
        return remove(seq[1:])
    else:
        return [seq[0]] + remove(seq[1:])

print(remove(["a", "b", "c", ["d", "e"], "f", "g", "h", "i"]))
```

Your second error was with the last `return` statement. You tried to join a string to the front of a list with the `+` operator. Effectively you were doing something like `"b" + ["c"]`, which throws an error. You can't add a list and a non-list together with `+`.

Thirdly, to maintain the structure of the nested lists, I had to wrap the return value of remove() in a list, in the case where we had a nested list `return [remove(seq[0])] + remove(seq[1:])`.

Comment: You also need to return an empty string in first `if` condition.

Comment: That's because of that you have changed the the last condition to `[seq[0]]`

Comment: Can I do this in a way that the initial structure of the list remains intact? So if I have sublists in the list they would remain: [a, b, [c, d, e], f] would become [b, [c, d], f]

Comment: @Galax did you understand my question? Can I do this in a way that the initial structure of the list remains intact? So if I have sublists in the list they would remain: [a, b, [c, d, e], f] would become [b, [c, d], f]

Comment: @user2831306 I've updated my answer to return nested lists, instead of flattening to one list.